# Footer cuts off on mobile browsers

Tags: html, mobile-safari, responsiveness

I'm having a problem with viewing a website I designed on mobile browsers. On the homepage, the footer is cutting off half of the page with it's contents cutting off at the bottom. I figured there wasn't enough height for all of the content and played around with height declarations for the body in CSS to no avail.

This is what it's suppose to look like.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is what's happening.

[image: Footer begins to overlap the rest of the page while the footer's contents are being cut off at the bottom of the page]

Does anyone have any suggestions? You can view the site at [www.lamarplaterimages.com](http://www.lamarplaterimages.com). I'm viewing it on an iPhone 11 using Safari. Firefox shows the same problem too. Everything looks the way it should using developing tools in web browsers.

Here's a little CSS for the footer and homepage inside the media query for 375px screen size.

```
/* Homepage CSS */

html, body {
height: 100%;
}   

.main {
height: 418%;

}

/* Footer CSS */

footer {
height: 90%;
}

.page-footer-logo {
margin-left: 18%;
transform: translateY(30%);
}

.page-footer-logo img {
width: 230px;
}

.contact-info {
margin-left: -2%;
transform: translateY(30%);
}

.contact-info p {
font-size: 17px;
line-height: 30px;
text-align: center;
}

.nav-links {
display: none;
}

.work-hours {
margin-left: -2%;
transform: translateY(-30%);
}

.work-hours p {
font-size: 17px;
line-height: 30px;
text-align: center;
}

.page-social-media-links {
transform: translateY(150%);
margin-left: 28%;
}

.ig-link {
flex: .47;

}
.fb-link {
flex: .47;
}

.jaliyadesigns-link {
margin-left: -2%;
margin-top: 30%;
transform: translateY(-150%);
}

.jaliyadesigns-link p {
font-size: 17px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: EDIT: Hey guys! I think I may know what is causing the problem. If you view the site and it looks a little janky, it's because I took out a piece of coding that was causing the problem. I'm going to chill out for the night and decompress and get back it tomorrow. Thanks for any future tips.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Viewport Units** like `vw` for **width** and `vh` for **height** instead of `px` or `%` for all your elements including **margin** and **font-size** because it will help you make your webpage/website responsive.

It should solve your issue but if it doesn't let me know in the comments, I will try my best to help you.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I did that and it dismantled the page when I checked it out using developing tools in Firefox.

Comment: @JanineWilliams Sad to hear that it didn't worked for you but can you do me a favour that whenever you solve your issue, please let me know how you did it, I would love to know how you solved it.

Comment: To fix an issue I had with white space appearing below the footer, I created a div for all of the content on the homepage except for the footer and gave it the class "main". That worked wonderful when viewing the website in a browser. When I viewed it on my phone, the footer overlapped the body content. I tried making "main" longer in height, but that did nothing. I went ahead and deleted it and now you can see all of the content. NOW the footer doesn't want to go to the bottom of the page. It's stuck in the middle of page behind other elements. Trying to fix this new issue now.

Comment: @JanineWilliams again give it the main class and use **Viewport Units** as i said in answer then your website will work in mobile and browser both. Please ket me know if it works. And thanks for saying me how you solved your issue.

Comment: @JanineWilliams Hey, hopping in real quick to check whether I solved your issue or do I need to ameliorate my skills?

Comment: Hey! I solved the issue. Once I got rid of the main div class, I was able to see the rest of homepage's content. I fixed the footer by going back to previous media queries and changing their positioning since the footer was showing up in the middle of the page for those screen sizes as well. That did the trick. Thanks again for your suggestion.

Comment: @JanineWilliams I am so happy that your issue is solved and my suggestion helped you and can you do me a favour that if I was able to help you even a bit so, please accept and upvote my answer, it would mean a lot to me. And thanks for saying me how your issue was completely, it made me so happy because you are the only one out of four whose issue was not able to solve and the other three never replied to me saying how they resolved it so a big thanks to you.

Comment: I changed all pixel and percentage units to viewport units like you suggested and it dismantled the layout. I ended up trying something else that I thought of and that worked out as far as keeping the footer from overlapping the homepage's content. I am still having a problem with mobile browsers cutting off the bottom of the footer. Sorry that I didn't state that before.

Comment: @JanineWilliams I am so sorry that it didn't worked for you but you can try Bootstrap Grid System to make your website responsive.

Comment: Since I'm almost done with this website, it wouldn't make sense to redo it in Bootstrap. However, I'm going to get into Bootstrap for future web projects. It seems like it makes your life easier.

Comment: @JanineWilliams Yup, bootstrap make it lot easier and you should also learn JavaScript because it will also help you a lot while making a website.